# SSIS via MSBuild - Could not load ...DTSRuntimeWrap

Tags: ssis, msbuild

I'm using the CodePlex-hosted Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Build project to build a DLL that contains the MSBuild tasks for building SSIS packages via MSBuild.exe.

I also am using an MSBuild `proj` file that's floating around the web.

More here:

https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/

I've opened the CodePlex project, disabled signing, switched it to 4.6.1 and built the DLL and corrected paths etc. and go it semi-working. However MSBuild spits this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've installed SSDT latest for Visual Studio 2015. I have various SQL Server editions installed on my dev PC. The DLL seems to be present; I've copied all I need into one folder for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the CodePlex project again and remove the reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS`.

Look on your local disk for the missing `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll` and note the version(s) you have available.

Now look on your disk for `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll` and note the version(s).

Re-add the reference but make sure you pick a DLL for which you also have the version of the 'wrap' available.

Now make sure those DLLs are (re)copied over into your working folder or whatever.

If you're still having problems, you may need to copy some files around so that `MSBuild.exe` can find them or edit/create a config file for MSBuild.

[How to solve: Custom MSBuild task requires assembly outside of AppBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690432/how-to-solve-custom-msbuild-task-requires-assembly-outside-of-appbase)